# How to reuse MyBatis's mapper in another mapper?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have tables `event` and `message`, which have one-to-one relationship and are represented by classes:

```
public class Event {
    private Long id;
    private Message message;
}

public class Message {
    private Long id;
}
```

And there are two mappers: `EventMapper` and `MessageMapper`:

```
public interface EventMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM event WHERE date BETWEEN #{from} AND #{to}")
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
            @Result(property = "message", column = "message_id",
                    javaType = Message.class, one = @One(select = "getMessage"))
    })
    List<Event> selectInInterval(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to);

    @Select("SELECT * FROM message WHERE id = #{id}")
    Message getMessage(@Param("id") Long id);
}


public interface MessageMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM message WHERE id = #{id}")
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
            @Result(property = "text", column = "text")
    })
    List<Event> selectById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

`EventMapper` selects events and maps them via an annotation, using `getMessage` to select and map event's message. But I already have identical method `selectById` in `MessageMapper`, so is it possible to reuse it?

Comment: Why not use inheritance? If message is a type of event make it extend the event and make MessageMapper extend EventMapper. The `EventManager` shouldn't use `getMessage` if you want to distinguish between event and message.

Comment: These are different types, message does not extend event. Of course, it's possible to create something like `GetMessagable` interface, but obviously it would be an ugly solution.

Comment: So you have a message which is not an event. but an event that always has a message. So what does keep you from extending the MessageMapper in the EventMapper like `EventMapper extends MessageMapper` and then just use the inherited selectById function? Doesn't sound like an ugly solution to me right now. But we also don't know the full spectrum of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use any definition from the other mapper including a statement or `ResultMap` you should include `namespace` (fully qualified name) of the mapper into the identifier of that entity.

In your example assuming that `MessageMapper` is in `com.company.app.mappers` package it would be:

```
public interface EventMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM event WHERE date BETWEEN #{from} AND #{to}")
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
            @Result(property = "message", column = "message_id",
                    javaType = Message.class,
                    one = @One(select = "com.company.app.mappers.MessageMapper.getMessage"))
    })
    List<Event> selectInInterval(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.